# Change Javascript Variable from PHP

Tags: javascript, database, variables

i really have a Problem.. i try to build a little Game with Javascript, until now the Game is working.. now i want to save 2 variables in a mysql database and loading them back in the Game

Saving in Database is working good, and loading them works too. I can read the Value's in the Console.. but i really dont know how to work with them now.. all isnt working.. pls help me.. im really no to this and wanna learn it..here my code..

**Update**
hm i cant get it work.. maybe i tell u what i want to do.. maybe there is an easier method..

i build a small "slot machine". I wanna save the amount of alltime spins..and alltime wins

on spin button click i count +1 to my "score" variable.. on win +1 to "twins" Both are saving successfully in mysqli database cause javascript just clientside...

now i just need to load the score and twins variable when loading this index.html.. and after each spin..

i see both variables in the Console.log, this works great.. but i really dont know how to use them and ur answer didnt helped me.. couldnt get it to work..

i think i need to give up...

Index.html

```
<script> openUserTimes(); var score = "" var twins = "" spins.innerHTML = "Alltime Spins : " + score wins.innerHTML = "Alltime Wins : " + twins var doing = false; let status = document.getElementById("status") var info = true; function openUserTimes(username) { $.post( "returndata.php", { name: "Slot" }, function(response) { var score = response.amount var twins = response.times console.log('Retreived score:'+ response.amount ); //<<<<<<<<< i can see the right database entry.. console.log('Retreived twins:'+ response.times ); } //<<<<<<<<< works too.. ); } function saveUserTimes() { $.post("savesettings.php", { name: "Slot", amount: score, times: twins, }, function(data,status){ $( "#saveWarningText" ).fadeIn(100); setTimeout(function(){ $( "#saveWarningText" ).fadeOut(100); }, 3000); }); } .... .... </script>
```

my
**returndata.php**

```
      .....$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }


        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
        $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['amount']);
        $times = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['times']);

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usertimes WHERE name ="'. $name. '"';

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $response = array();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $response['name'] = $row["name"];
               $response['amount'] = $row["amount"];
                $response['times'] = $row["times"];
            }

        echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            echo "  0 results";
        }
```

Sorry for my bad englisch..

Comment: Can you add html code. On my previous response, $(document).ready(function() is load when your page is loaded. After you need a button event to increment score. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your global variables. if you declare new variable with key "var", this values can not update your variables in global scope.

It's a very basic example how you can interact with your javascript. You need JQuery library but i believe you already import.

html

```
<button id="mybutton">
Cliquer ici
</button>

<br /><br />

Score :
<div id="score" style="font-size:16px; color:#009900;">
0
</div>
```

javascript + **jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var game1 = Object.create(myGame);
   game1.init();


   $('#mybutton').on('click', function(){
      game1.play(10);
   });

});



const myGame = {

   score: 0,
   twins: "",

   init: function() {
      this.score = 0;
   },

   play: function(score) {
      this.score += score;
      this.updateScore();
   },
   updateScore: function(){
      $('#score').html(this.score);
   }
}
```

I made a jsfiddle for you :
https://jsfiddle.net/3d96txma/1/